# Десериализация строки

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите как десериализовать строку типа

```
{property(field1=value, field2=value, field3=value, field4=value, ...)}
```

Именно без кавычек и field всегда различны

Comment: `property` - может быть разным?

Comment: Да, но он заранее известен

Comment: А что может быть в value? Например, может ли там быть строка? Или что-то другое, содержащее запятую или пробел?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Честно говоря, имея такую строку не вижу смысла даже парсить регексом.

Просто чекаем строку на начало/конец и стартуем создавать словарь...

```
public IDictionary<string, string> Parse(string propertyName, string dataString)
{
    string startsWith = $"{{{propertyName}(";
    const string endsWith = ")}";
    if (!dataString.StartsWith(startsWith) || !dataString.EndsWith(endsWith))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(dataString));
    }

    dataString = dataString.Substring(startsWith.Length, dataString.Length - startsWith.Length - endsWith.Length);
    var dict = dataString
        .Split(',')
        .Select(kv => kv.Trim().Split('='))
        .ToDictionary(kv => kv.ElementAtOrDefault(0), kv => kv.ElementAtOrDefault(1));

    return dict;
}
```

[Тестить](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WdPZGD)!

Comment: Спасибо огромное!